# Facing issue with SSL soap connectivity

Tags: ssl, soap

I am currently facing issue in connecting to a soap https service from soapui. I am provided with public and private certificates. I have added the public certificate in the preferences--> SSL setting tab. And then I have configured the outgoing ws security --> keystore with the private key. Also I have created a signature with the private certificate. 
When I hit the service am getting a soap response saying "certificate is not trusted" . Am new to this setup and please correct me if am wrong.Can you please help me in resolving the issue ?

Comment: did you tried to read `api` or you may be using wrong approach , no one can tell if you will not post some relevant data.

Comment: I am facing certificate is not trusted issue. Could you tell me how to fix this issue ?